# Faça um programa que receba 5 números e mostre a saída a seguir:. C++

Tags: array, c++, formatação

Estou tendo dificuldade na formatação da saída o código está funcionando certo, alguem tem ideia de como posso corrigir a saída

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <clocale>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    int seq[5], contS = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
        cout << "Digite o " << i << "º número: ";
        cin >> seq[i];
        contS = seq[i] + contS;
    }

    cout << "Os números digitados foram: ";
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
        cout << seq[i] << " + ";
    }
    cout << " = " << contS;


    return 0;
}
```

Entrada: 1  2  3  4  5

Saida esperada: "Os números digitados foram: 1+2+3+4+5 = 15"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma pena misturar C com C++, mas vamos lá.

O último elemento não pode ter o sinal de mais, então ele tem que ser tratado como exceção e não dentro do laço, até porque não tem porque pagar ineficiência com um *branch* dentro do laço.

Organizando um pouco melhor o código e corrigindo o erro de acesso aos índices (que não aconteceria se usasse vetor do C++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int seq[5], contS = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << "Digite o " << i << "º número: ";
        cin >> seq[i];
        contS += seq[i];
    }
    cout << "Os números digitados foram: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) cout << seq[i] << " + ";
    cout << seq[4];
    cout << " = " << contS;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/in7Azf). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/lkwfdxnq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/LastItemInLoop.cpp).

Answer (score 2):

Espero que isso te satisfaça , fiquei quebrando a cabeça pra não tentar fazer a gambiarra

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <clocale>

using namespace std;

int main(){

setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

int seq[5], contS = 0;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    cout << "Digite o " << i+1 << "º número: ";
    cin >> seq[i];
    contS += contS;
}

cout << "Os números digitados foram: ";
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    if(i==4){cout<<seq[i];}
    else{cout << seq[i] << "+";}
}
cout << " = " << contS;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT:
> Foram corrigidas a faixa de indices utilizados.
> Em C++ os índices dos arrays começam em 0.

Use uma uma [expressão ternária condicional](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/)

```
//Se i < 4 insere uma string " + " na saída padrão, senão não faz nada.
cout << seq[i] << (i < 4 ? " + " : "");
```

No seu exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <clocale>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    int seq[5], contS = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
        cout << "Digite o " << i + 1 << "º número: ";
        cin >> seq[i];
        contS = seq[i] + contS;
    }

    cout << "Os números digitados foram: ";
    for(int i=0; i<=4; i++){
        cout << seq[i] << (i<4 ? " + " : "");
    }
    cout << " = " << contS;


    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Digite o 1º número: 1
Digite o 2º número: 2
Digite o 3º número: 3
Digite o 4º número: 4
Digite o 5º número: 5
Os números digitados foram: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, tinha me esquecido desse operador

Comment: `int i=1;i<=5`  agora que eu vi isso está errado. Em c++ os vetorescomeçam do indice 0